# Passing Extra Parameters in express - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, express, scope

I'm trying to remove the anonymous functions from my node application. For instance:

```
app.post('/page-edit.json', function (req, res) {
    db.get(req.body.page_id, function (err, doc) {
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

So say I break out the inner function:

```
function innerMost(err, doc) {
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send(doc);
}

function outer(err, doc) {
     db.get(req.body.page_id, innerMost);
}


app.post('/page-edit.json', outer);
```

The question is, how do I pass extra parameters, like 'res' into 'innerMost'? It's getting lost in the process.

If you want to see the source code (or even want to contribute to the open source project!) you can see it [here](https://github.com/maned/goblin)!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best you can do with regular JS:

```
function outer(req, res) {
    function innerMost(err, doc) {
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send(doc);
    }

    db.get(req.body.page_id, innerMost);
}

app.post('/page-edit.json', outer);
```

However, you might want to look into various async libraries such as https://github.com/caolan/async. If you want to venture even further, you could look into using icedcoffeescript http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/, which is pretty good in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is `currying` (also known as "partial application of functions") which basically lets you prefill the values of some parameters ahead of time.

John Resig has a nice writeup on [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/).

Grabbing some code from his writeup, you can create a `partial` function like this:

```
Function.prototype.partial = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function(){
      var arg = 0;
      for ( var i = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++ )
        if ( args[i] === undefined )
          args[i] = arguments[arg++];
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

And in your case, use it like this:

```
function innerMost(err, doc, req, res) {
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send(doc);
}

function outer(req, res) {
    //partially apply `innerMost` here by passing in `req` and `res`
    db.get(req.body.page_id, innerMost.partial(undefined, undefined, req, res));
}

app.post('/page-edit.json', outer);
```

Note, this code isn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to separate things out using Function.bind(), so you don't need to mess with Function's prototype, external libs, etc..

```
function innermost(req, res, e, r){
    res.end(r)
}

function somedbfunc(q, cb){
    cb(null, 'db results');
}

function outer(req, res){
    somedbfunc('query', innermost.bind(this, req, res));
}

app.all('*', outer)
    ==> "db results"
```